# Scoping: Local vs Var

Tags: coldfusion, scope, coldfusion-9

I'm new to CF so this may be a basic question. But I've heard I should use local for objects inside functions due to how scoping works in CF. But what about 'var'? Is var the same as using local?

e.g.

```
function MyFunction()
{
    local.obj = {};
}
```

Is this the same as:

```
function MyFunction()
{
    var obj = {};
}
```

If they aren't the same, what is the difference between them? And when should I be using either of them?

Comment: Related article: http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2013/12/34-dumb-things-coldfusion-does.html

Comment: And a bunch of related links: http://www.carehart.org/blog/client/index.cfm/2010/3/4/resources_on_the_var_scope_problem

Comment: Both are same when it comes to declaring but the difference lies in the further usage. If a VAR declaration is not made before then the variable can search its value in all the other scopes but using LOCAL prevents this(and any unexpected cases).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are very similar, but not exactly the same. Both only exist inside of a function but they work slightly differently.

The `var` version works it way through all the default variable scopes. See http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec09af4-7fdf.html

Local will match only a variable in a local scope. Consider the following

```
<cffunction name="himom">
    <cfoutput>
        <p><b>try 0:</b> #request_method#</p>
        <!--- you might think that the variable does not exist, 
              but it does because it came from cgi scope --->
    </cfoutput> 

    <cfquery name="myData" datasource="Scorecard3">
        SELECT 'This is via query' AS request_method
    </cfquery>
    <!--- Data is now being loaded into a query --->

    <cfoutput query="myData">
        <p><b>try 1:</b> #request_method#</p>
    </cfoutput>
    <!--- This one now came from the query --->        

    <cfset var request_method = "This is Var">
    <!--- We now declare via var ---> 
 
    <cfoutput query="myData">
        <p><b>try 2:</b> #request_method#</p>
    </cfoutput> 
    <!--- the query version disappears and now 
          the var version takes precedence --->

    <cfset local.request_method = "This is local">
    <!--- now we declare via local --->

    <cfoutput query="myData">
        <p><b>try 3:</b> #request_method#</p>
    </cfoutput>
    <!--- The local method takes precedence --->

    <cfoutput>
        <p><b>try 4:</b> #request_method#</p>
        <!--- in fact it even takes precedence over the var --->

        <p><b>try 5:</b> #local.request_method#</p>
        <!--- there is no question where this comes from --->   
   </cfoutput>
</cffunction>

<cfset himom()>
```

**Results of the above**

try 0: GET

try 1: This is via query

try 2: This is Var

try 3: This is local

try 4: This is local

try 5: This is local

**In summary**

When developing, you could use either to make sure that variables only exist inside of a function, but always prefixing your variables with `local` goes a long way in making sure that your code is clearly understood

Comment: thanks. Just wondering, if you reference say "local.obj" later on in your function/method, should you still use "local.obj" or can you just refer to it as "obj"? e.g. would this be fine:
`function MyFunction() { local.obj = {}; obj["test"] = "hello"; }`

Comment: IMHO, you should be using `local.obj`. While your question is not about Railo, http://blog.getrailo.com/post.cfm/performance-tuning covers Railo's options on this.

Comment: malik, you only _need_ `var obj` or `local.obj` when writing the variable - when reading it is optional. Some people prefer always scoping, others prefer not to bother with certain scopes (like local).

Comment: @JamesAMohler: I do not understand the difference, as you have declared `<cfset local.request_method = "This is local">` after `<cfset var request_method = "This is Var">` I think for that local scope overwrites the previous value.But no way local takes precedence over var as both are same. Am I correct?

Answer (score 5):

In ColdFusion 9+, using the local scope and the var directive in a ColdFusion CFC provide the same result.

Ben Forta explains it here:
http://forta.com/blog/index.cfm/2009/6/21/The-New-ColdFusion-LOCAL-Scope

I would recommend using the local. notation as it is more explicit.