# Scope of var and variables

Tags: scope, coldfusion, cfml

If I have a function like

```cfml
<cfscript>
function say(what) {
  var a = what;
  variables.b = what;
  return what;
}
</cfscript>
```

I thought the scope of a was `variables`, but dumping `variables` returns just `b`. What is the scope of a?

Comment: I believe a is in the local scope. It should exist only within the function.

Comment: When you use `var` the scope of the variable is limited to the function. The same as using `local.a`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declaring a variable using the `var` keyword puts it into the `local` scope, not the `variables` scope.

Answer (score 4):

This really is a comment, but it is way too long. Consider the following code

```
<cfscript>
function doMath() {
   var a = 1;
   local.b = 2;
   return a + local.b;
   }
</cfscript>
```

At first glance on might think that `var` and `local.` have the same scope. After all they both exist only within the function. When then function is done, both variables cease to exist. End of story? Maybe not.

In ColdFusion, we have both implied scopes and implicit scopes.

```
url.a
form.a
cookie.a
session.a
application.a
local.a
arguments.a
myQuery.a
```

Are all different. If I have all of the above as valid variables and I say `<cfoutput>#a#</cfoutput>` which `a` do I get? ColdFusion goes through its list of implied scopes until it hit one that matches. And that is the one that gets displayed. So back to the question.

So when I am inside of a function, if I use `var` I am saying to ColdFusion, look through all the implied scopes until you find one that matches. If I use `local.a`, I am saying look in exactly one place and use that.

**Benefits**

I know exactly what variable I am picking up. If you are writing code that needs to be as fast as possible you won't use implicit scopes. If you are writing code that is the most readable, you won't use implicit scopes.

So no. `var` is not the same as `local.`

Comment: I know it can be more readable and less typing to not include scopes, but after having had to chase down some weird scope issues, I'm all for being _very_ explicit in my intent. :-)

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313963/scoping-local-vs-var/22314824#22314824

Answer (score 4):

Understanding scoping can help you avoid some issues that can be *extremely* difficult to track down. For all intents an purposes, `var a` puts `a` into the `local` scope, and it can be referenced as a `local` variable. And if declared afterwards, it will overwrite any `a` variable already in the `local` scope.

https://trycf.com/gist/faf04daa53194a5fad2e69e164518299/acf2016?theme=monokai

```cfml
<cfscript>
function say() {
    local.a = "local" ; 
    var b   = "var" ;

    lv = local.b ; // We didn't explicitly assign b to Local scope. 

    try {
        v = variables ; // Let's dump the variables scope. 
    } catch (any e) {
        v = "Error: " & e.message ;
    }

    variables.nh = "Now here." ; // Explicitly populate variables scope.

    var c = "var c" ; // We have a variables scope, what happens to var?

    try {
        v2 = variables ; // Let's dump the variables scope. 
    } catch (any e) {
        v2 = "Error: " & e.message ;
    }

    var d = "var" ;
    local.d = "local" ;

    local.e = "local" ;
    var e = "var" ;

    return {
        a  : a ,       // Local.
        b  : b ,       // Var.
        d  : d ,       // Which one?
        e  : e ,       // Which one?
        el : local.e , // Which one?? 
        l  : lv ,      // Ref b in local scope.
        l2 : local ,   // Dump local scope.
        v  : v ,       // There doesn't seem to be a variables scope yet.
        v2 : v2        // Defined a variable scope and now here.
    } ;
}

writeDump(say());
</cfscript>
```

[image: Output 1]

We can see above that declaring `var b` puts `b` into the `local` scope, and that the `variables` scope doesn't exist until we declare something into it. We can reference `local.b`, but `variables.b` can't exist. After we explicitly created and populated `variables` scope with `nh`, we create a `var c`. This doesn't go into the `variables` scope either, but into the `local` scope.

When a variable is declared with the same name in either `local` or by `var`, the last one declared will overwrite the other one (see `d`,`e` and `el`). **Watch out for this.**

Also note that the empty `arguments` scope from the function is also in the `local` scope.

On that note, my last two observation of scope things to watch out for:

https://trycf.com/gist/65b73e7a57d0434049d0eb9c0d5f9687/acf11?theme=monokai

```cfml
<cfscript>
function ks() {
    variables.jay   = "Snoogins." ; // variables scope leaks out of function.
    local.silentbob = "____" ;      // local scope stays inside function.
}

function sayArgs(arg) {
    local.arg = "local" ; // Order after agruments in CF10 but not 2016.

    ks() ; // Run ks() function to instantiate jay and silentbob.

    return {
        arg    : arg ,       // CF10 = arguments scope. CF11+ = local scope.
        args   : arguments ,
        local  : local ,     // No leakage from ks().
        vars   : variables   // Jay leaks from ks().
    } ;
}

writeDump(sayArgs("argue")) ;
</cfscript>
```

[image: Output 2]

Two things I noted here:

First, there is a difference between the order of evaluation of `arguments` and `local` scopes in CF10 vs later CF versions. Current CF2016 (or 2011+) behavior is that `local` scope inside of a function will not overwrite the `arguments` scope, but it will be evaluated first. The opposite happens in CF10: `arguments` is evaluated first. Lucee and Railo behave like ACF2016.

The second note has to do with variable leakage as it applies to `variables` and `local`. `local` will only exist inside the function that it is declared in. `variables` is more global and can be reached outside of the function.

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/the-cfml-programming-language/using-coldfusion-variables/about-scopes.html << For ACF2016. Displays evaluation order with `local` over `arguments`.

http://www.learncfinaweek.com/week1/Scopes/ << Lists the order that ACF10 evaluates in, but the order of `arguments` and `local` are switched in later versions.

https://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec09af4-7fdf.html << This is the documentation for ACF9. It lists the same order as ACF2016, but is different in ACF10. I don't have a copy of CF9 to test against right now, so I don't know how CF9 and earlier handle the evaluations.

Answer (score 3):

Let's go line by line (see the comments):

```
<cfscript>
function say(what) {

    // using the "var" keyword define a variable named "a" in the "local" scope
    // the "local" scope is private to the current function context
    // give to "a" the value of the "what" argument
  var a = what;


    // explicitly define a variable "b" in the "variables" scope 
    // the "variables" scope is available anywhere in the current template context
    // give to "b" the value of the "what" argument
  variables.b = what;


    // return the value of "what" argument
  return what;
}
</cfscript>
```

`var` is a **keyword**
`variables` is a **scope**
`local` is a **private scope** (also a keyword)

The `local` scope can be populated either using `var a = "foo"` or explicitly using `local.a = "foo"`.

Answer (score 0):

In the current example, var `a` is available only within the scope of the function.