# Defining variables in cfscript ColdFusion?

Tags: variables, coldfusion, cfml, coldfusion-2016

I tried to rewrite my `Application.cfc` and other `.cfc` files in my system with `cfscript`. There is few things that I'm not sure how they work in cfscript. I'm wondering about defining variables inside of the functions. For example `onRequestStart()` function looks like this:

```
function onRequestStart(required string thePage) returntype="boolean" output="false" {
        var request.appCode = "MyApp";
        var request.appName = "Single Page Application";
        var page = listLast(arguments.thePage,"/");
        var onApplicationStart();

        if(!listFindNoCase("Home.cfm,Auth.cfc",page)){
            if(structKeyExists(SESSION, "loggedin") AND SESSION.loggedin EQ false){
                location(url="https://www.myapp.org", addToken="false");
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Do I need to use `var` word in situations where I'm defining `request/session` variables? If I do what is the best practice, use var word or use `local.variablename`? Is `local` and `variables` same in `cfscript`?

Comment: Nothing to do with the question. Why are you calling onApplicationStart at the beginning of every request?

Comment: @Ageax I use that in case when I need to restart application variables. That line is commented out. I'm still in development process. Hope this make sense.

Comment: Gotcha.  Just wasn't sure if it was going into Prod, which would be .. bad ;-)

Comment: Btw., if you want to, you can restart your application when a specific URL parameter is set. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14362012/432681.

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47112598/scope-of-var-and-variables/47114142#47114142

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`var` is used only for local variables. That means variables which are/should not be accessible outside the function definition. `Session` & `Request` are accessible to each session & request respectively. Putting them on `var` scope will give terrible results.

You can use either `var` or `local`, both have 'local' scope. `Variables` is the page scope and any variable defined in the `Variables` scope will be accessible to all functions in the CFC.

```
function onRequestStart(required string thePage) returntype="boolean" output="false" {
    request.appCode = "MyApp";
    request.appName = "Single Page Application";
    var page = listLast(arguments.thePage,"/");
  //this is a function call and not variable declaration.   
  onApplicationStart();

    if(!listFindNoCase("Home.cfm,Auth.cfc",page)){
        if(structKeyExists(SESSION, "loggedin") AND SESSION.loggedin EQ false){
            location(url="https://www.myapp.org", addToken="false");
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I wasn't sure how this can be replaced in CFML `<cfset structDelete(session,"username")>` since I do not need to define anything in this case just call the function. thanks for explaining variables and scopes.

Comment: Just drop the cfset and add a semi-colon at the end: `structDelete(session, "username");`

Answer (score 3):

`var` is *not* equal to the `<cfset>` tag, i.e. you can't do a simple search & replace when switching to CFScript syntax.

`var` is only used for local variable definitions. This means, setting structure and array items, like `request`, `session` and other scope variables should not be prefixed by `var`.
Also, function calls must be written without preceding `var`.

`local` and `var` both refer to the local scope. Though note, as mentioned above, if you want to define variables via `local.something` the `var` keyword is also not needed.

`variables`, in contrary to `local`, refers to the page scope, which is accessible from everywhere within the component and any included pages.

For more info on the different scopes, you should [read the Adobe docs](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/the-cfml-programming-language/using-coldfusion-variables/about-scopes.html).

Comment: Good points. Definitely shouldn't use var on persistent scopes. Though curiously var behaves differently with persistent scopes than local - and what I'd have expected.  https://trycf.com/gist/1e19e31113a38d682a5ca130f10d83db/acf2016?theme=monokai

Comment: Interesting! Note that Adobe ColdFusion and Lucee behave differently in this case. Obviously, Adobe ColdFusion just ignores the `var` and assigns the variable to the global scope. Lucee is more consistent and handles `var` and `local.` equally putting the variables into the local scope. Another interesting thing to note is that the structure variable holding `firstVar` and `secondVar` gets automatically defined.

Comment: I hadn't notice Lucee's behavior was different. It's handling makes more sense to me. Guess it's not surprising. There's a few areas, like with scopes, where Adobe CF's handling is a bit of IMO.