# CFSCRIPT - For loop increments the index wrong

Tags: for-loop, scope, coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I might have been found a bug in ColdFusion 2016.
I have two functions. The first one has a loop which iterates from 1 to n and pushes the return value of the second function which is also an array into an array. I noticed that;
index value is 1,
calling function and pushing the value into the array,
and index value is the end value of the loop.
Is this a bug?

```
<cfscript>
public array function fnc1(required array p1, required array p2, required numeric pSize, required numeric qSize, required numeric dSize){
iterationNum = pSize/2;
point = randRange(1, qSize-1);
for(i = 1; i <= iterationNum; i++){
    writeOutput(i); // prints: 1
    pop[i] = fnc2(p1[i], p2[i], point);
    writeOutput(i); // prints: iterationNum value
    writeDump(var = pop[i], label = "pop-"&i);
}
writeDump(var = pop, label="pop");
}

public array function fnc2(required array p1, required array p2, required numeric point){
n = arrayLen(p1);
concatArr = arrayNew(1);
for(i = 1; i <= point; i++){
    concatArr[i] = p1[i];
}
for(i = point + 1; i <= n; i++){
    concatArr[i] = p2[i];
}
writeDump(var=concatArr, label="Concated Array");
return concatArr;
}
</cfscript>
```

Comment: I think it's your code.  Specifically, you are not keeping your variables local to your functions.  Variable `i` is being generated in fnc1, and overwritten in fnc2.

Comment: even if i change the name of my variable in the first function and keep the same in the second function, i get the same error. Still, i don`t think it is about my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default scope of a variable inside of a `cfc` is not function only. But rather it is cfc wide. This is often problematic.

Similarly, the default scope of a variable outside of a `cfc` is request wide. This is often useful.

### Two approaches

There are two approaches to limit the scope of a variable inside of a `cfc`. One is to use the keyword `var`, the other is the use `local.`

It is a long story as to how they are different. The sample solution below uses var throughout. If you want to know more about `var` vs `local.`, click here: [Scoping: Local vs Var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313963/scoping-local-vs-var)

```
<cfscript>
public array function fnc1(required array p1, required array p2, required numeric pSize, required numeric qSize, required numeric dSize){
   var iterationNum = pSize/2;
   var point = randRange(1, qSize-1);
   for(var i = 1; i <= iterationNum; i++){
       writeOutput(i); // prints: 1
       pop[i] = fnc2(p1[i], p2[i], point);
       writeOutput(i); // prints: iterationNum value
       writeDump(var = pop[i], label = "pop-"&i);
   }
   writeDump(var = pop, label="pop");
}

public array function fnc2(required array p1, required array p2, required numeric point){
   var n = arrayLen(p1);
   var concatArr = arrayNew(1);
   for(var i = 1; i <= point; i++){
      concatArr[i] = p1[i];
      }
   for(var ii = point + 1; ii <= n; ii++){
      concatArr[ii] = p2[ii];
      }
   writeDump(var=concatArr, label="Concated Array");
   return concatArr;
   }
</cfscript>
```

Comment: *This is often problematic.* Yup. @sdiri - Do take a look at ALL function variables, not just the indexes (`pop[i]`, etc..). Also, scoping all variable references is a good practice, like using `arguments.p1` instead of just `p1`. Makes for more readable code.